# Getting the selected files path from a custom application in context menu

Tags: windows, copy, contextmenu

I have a scenario where I keep copying a bunch of files to same folder and if it exists, I rename the original file there and copy the files. I want to automate this process.
I was checking if I can add a context menu option which shows on right-click in Windows.
I followed few tutorials which had gave me a way to add a program to the context menu by modifying regkeys.
But that just starts the program, I wanted to know how to get the paths of the items selected for copy to. Is there a way to achieve this? Or am I going down a wrong path?

I have added this command to context menu with my programs exe as value.

[image]

I want to know how to get the paths of selected items in my program.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this.
When adding regkey for the context menu command specify it as following
"PathToExe.exe""%1". This passes the selected folder/file full as the first argument